Can you give me a second opinion about my workout?
I cannot afford a gym or any equipment, so I'm trying to be resourceful and workout at a local park using bodyweight exercises. I wanted to ask if I could make my workout any more efficient so that it's relative to working out at a gym and make consistent gains 
Although I've asked a similar question like this, I wanted to make some adjustments to my new workout routine.
Thanks so much in advance!
Push Day:
Push ups 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Incline Push-Ups 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Decline Push-Ups 3 sets of 6-10 reps
Tricep Dips 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Shoulder Taps 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Pull Day:
Inverted Rows 3 sets of 6-10 reps
Pull ups 3 sets of 3-5 reps
Supermans 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Bodyweight Bicep Curls 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Concentration Curls 3 sets of 8-12 reps, 7 kgs
Leg + abs day:
Squats 3 sets of 15-20 reps
Lunges 3 sets of 12-15 reps
Glute Bridges 3 sets of 15-20 reps
Calf Raises 3 sets of 15-20 reps
Wall sits 3 sets of 1 min
Bicycle Crunches 3 sets of 20 reps
Planks 3 sets of 1 min
Lying Leg Raises 3 sets of 12-15 reps
Plank to Side Planks 3 sets of 6-10 reps
